# Das Genus der Nomina auf -sal

Tags: gender, history

Ich habe auf dem iPad (Duden Wissensnetz) nachgeschlagen und bemerke:

> Wirrsal, Labsal und Saumsal: das oder die
>
> Mühsal und Trübsal: die
>
> Irrsal und Schicksal: das

Es bleibt noch zu prüfen, ob andere Werke dies bestätigen. Aber falls ja:

Haben wir es hier mit unterschiedlichen Wortstämmen zu tun, die im Neuhochdeutschen verschwimmen? Oder verschiebt sich das Genus? Was geschieht hier?

---

Nebenbemerkung

Ich habe ähnliche Fragen bei den Wörtern auf -mut laienhaft erforscht. Dort korrelierte das Genus nach meinen ersten Erkenntnissen sehr oft damit, ob direkt aus Mut abgeleitet, oder aus Adjektiven auf -mutig rückgebildet wurde. Auf den ersten Blick erkenne ich diese Möglichkeit bei *Mühsal/mühselig*, Trübsal/trübselig und *Saumsal/saumselig*. Es muss aber geklärt werden, welcher Begriff jeweils älter war.

In diesem Zusammenhang ist diese [Abhandlung](http://www.kath.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/imperia/md/content/nt/nt/verkuendigungjesubergpredigt/selig.pdf) interessant, die historische Begriffe anspricht, welche mir nicht geläufig waren. Etwa *Armsal*.

Comment: Ein bißchen Rumsuchen macht die Sache noch komplizierter: Wiktionary sagt zu *Mühsal* (f/n), mit (n) veraltet. Anscheinend sind alle -sale, die noch in Verwendung sind, außer dem *Schicksal* (n) nur noch feminin. Grimm sagt zur *Trübsal* "(n/f, früher auch m[!!])"

Comment: Interessant ist auch *Drangsal* - das scheint das einzige Nomen aus dieser Gruppe zu sein, zu dem es auch ein direkt abgeleitetes Verb, *drangsalieren*, gibt. Oder findet jemand noch ein anderes?

Comment: Hattest Du bei Deiner Suche auch [diesen Wiktionary-Eintrag](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/-sal) gesehen? Dort wird der _Kluge_ zitiert und die Herkunft von _-sal_ aus germanisch _–sla- m_, bzw. _-slō- f_ abgeleitet. Leider steht dort nichts weiter dazu, ob diese beiden Suffixe mit der heutigen Genus-Bildung einhergehen. Vielleicht ist der _Kluge_ da ergiebiger, leider habe ich den aber nicht zur Hand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versuch einer stochiastischen Antwort

Im [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Wortbildungen/-sal) findet sich eine Liste der Wörter, die auf -sal enden:

- Drangsal, f (veraltet n)
- Irrsal, n
- Labsal, f, n
- Mühsal, f (veraltet n)
- Redsal, n
- Rinnsal, n
- Saumsal, f, n
- Scheusal, n
- Schicksal, n
- Trübsal, f
- Wirrsal, f, n
- Zwangsal, n

Schaut man ein wenig weiter, findet man dass sich alle Wörterbücher darin einig sind, dass das Suffix -sal noch "aktiv, aber nicht mehr produktiv" (bildet also keine neuen Wörter mehr) sei. Es handelt sich also um ein "eingefrorenes" Wortbildungsinstrument der deutschen Sprache.

Erstaunlich ist, dass der Grimm für *Trübsal* angibt:

> TRÜBSAL, f. , älter auch n. **und m.**

(das habe ich sonst nirgendwo gefunden). Es scheinen also für Wörter auf -sal möglicherweise einmal **alle** Genera möglich gewesen zu sein.

Schaut man sich die Liste oben einmal durch, so scheint es, als ob Bildungen auf -sal (zumindestens die, die heute noch gebräuchlich sind), die die passive Empfindungswelt betreffen (*Drangsal*, *Labsal*, *Trübsal*) eher feminin seien, und andere, die eher die Aussenwelt addressieren (*Schicksal*, *Scheusal*, *Rinnsal*) eher Neutren sind. Das entspricht auch ziemlich gut meinem eigenen Sprachgefühl.