# Wörter mit drei Artikeln

Tags: article, dictionary, duden

Sowohl laut [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Unbill) als auch laut [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Unbill) kann das Wort „Unbill“ sowohl den Artikel „der“ als auch die Artikel „die“ oder „das“ tragen. Welche Wörter gibt es noch, bei denen das der Fall ist und weshalb kann man beim Wort „Unbill“ alle drei verwenden?

Comment: Halb im Ernst: der Corona(Virus, modern), das Corona(Virus, altmodisch), die Corona(Grippe) ;)

Comment: @Ludi, und ich dachte, das wäre ein Bier.

Comment: Gleiche Aussprache, drei Genera: [der Coup](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Coup), die Kuh, das Q.

Comment: (obsolet) *Ungestüm*; heute in Grimm, DWB gelesen

Comment: @Ludi oder ohne Artikel, wie ein Eigenname.

Comment: Ich wundere mich ein wenig, dass der Beitrag nicht schon längst als Duplikat geschlossen worden ist. Denn es gibt ja bereits die [Liste deutscher Substantive mit mehreren Genera](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/liste-deutscher-substantive-mit-mehreren-genera) als Community-Wiki.

Comment: Alle männlichen und sächlichen Substantive haben sogar 5 Artikel: 1. »**Der** Schüler schläft.« 2. »Der Ball **des** Schülers ist rund.« 3. »Der Ball gehört **dem** Schüler.« 4. »Ich sehe **den** Schüler.« 5. »**Die** Schüler schlafen.« Zählt man auch die unbestimmten Artikel mit, sind es sogar noch mehr. - Die Frage sollte daher eigentlich lauten: »Substantive mit drei grammatischen Geschlechtern«

Answer (score 5):

Das ist der Beginn einer Liste, die ich im Laufe der Monate auszubauen hoffe.

### Selbes Nomen, drei Genera

- **Der, die das Furunkel**
  Der Duden schreibt nämlich:

> Substantiv, maskulin, oder Substantiv, Neutrum

Während Grimm das Femininum verlangt und belegt:

> mit einem erklecklichen hühnerauge am grossen zäh, der sie, wenns ander wetter wurde, wie eine furunkel brannte. Musäus kinderklapper (1788)

- **Das, die, (sehr selten) der Spinnweb(e)**
  Eigentlich ist es das Spinnweb, weil es ein Geweb ist. Vgl. dazu Grimm:

> das geschlecht ist ursprünglich entsprechend mhd. spinnenweppe, n.; erst allmählich hat sich das femininum daneben eingebürgert

Die ursprüngliche Form ist noch bei Theodor Storm zu finden:

> Auch Frau Christine sah jetzt in den Hof hinaus, fuhr aber gleich darauf mit der Hand über ihre Augen, als gälte es, dort ein Spinnweb fortzuwischen.

Grimm verzeichnet das seltene Maskulinum in folgenden Belegen:

> ungewöhnlich als masculinum behandelt: (gott) auch die seinen lest verfolgen und erwurgen, als hette er nicht einen strohalm odder spynweb um sie her gezogen. Luther 23, 528, 217 Weim. ausg.; sie schlahen jre flügel nimmer nider und lassen keinen spinweb für jrem maul wachsen, daz si ja jr ding weit und breit ausbringen. 4, 270a;

- **Der Tauf, die, das Taufe** Das selbe Wort, bei dem sich aber außer im Maskulinum nur die Form mit -e durchsetzte. Belege aus dem Grimm

> (Maskulinum): wenn dir schon die erbesünd abgenommen wird durch den tauf.
> (Neutrum): das er gottes wort verlaugnet und das tauffe

- **Der, die, das Trübsal**, Grimm schreibt:

  > TRÜBSAL, f. , älter auch n. und m
- **Der, die, das Rooß oder Roß** (wohl höchstens noch wegen seiner Erwähnung in Dudens alter Rechtschreibregel geläufig) bezeichnet die Honigwabe.

Siehe dazu auch [Tofros Beitrag](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/46127/16039)

*An dieser Stelle sollten wir auch gleich klären, ob Sie auch an gleich geschriebenen unterschiedlichen Wörtern interessiert sind, sowie an Wörtern, bei denen sich die Bedeutungen im Laufe der Zeit durch unterschiedliches Genus diversifizierten*
Wenn ja, wären auf Grundlage von Grimm und Duden noch zu nennen:

### Mehrere Nomina, gleiche Schreibung

1. **Der Dort(Unkraut bromus secalinus), die Dort(Calyx), das Dort(das Jenseits)**
2. **Der Korpus (Körper), die Korpus (Schriftgrad) das Korpus (z.B. Texte)**
3. **Der Mark = Markt, die Mark (u.a. Währung) das Mark (z.B. in Knochen)**
4. **Der, das Wand (Stoff), die Wand (Gebäudeteil)**
5. **Der Pinkel(z.B. “feiner), die, das Pinkel(Urin)
6. **Der Zehnt (Abgabe), die Zehnt(sehr selten, s.u.), das Zehnt (Jahrzehnt)**
   Zum Femininum bemerkt Grimm:

> ein auffälliges f. im sinne von zehnter theil eines epha (hebr. 'issaron, griech. δέκαπον, lat. decima) erscheint siebenmal bei Luther

#### Moderne, vielleicht nicht belegbare Begriffe

1. Der Corona(ein Toyota), die Corona(der Sonne), das Corona (Bier)

Comment: mehrere Nomina mit gleicher Schreibung, aber z.T. unterschiedlicher Aussprache: "der/die/das Band"

Comment: @Arsak stimmt! Die Kategorie müssen wir vielleicht auch noch aufmachen!

Comment: Den Grimm als Beleg zu nehmen ist aber Schummeln!

Comment: @tofro Ganz und gar nicht! Warum denn das?

Comment: Weil der zum großen Teil eine Sprache dokumentiert, die es nicht mehr gibt.

Comment: @tofro dann sorge ich jetzt mal dafür, daß sie wieder etwas bekannter wird. Wenn ich nicht mehr bin, könnt ihr den Grimm ja verbrennen ;)

Comment: Beim Pinkel fehlt natürlich noch die Wurst zum Kohl, (m)

Answer (score 3):

Eine Liste mit deutschen Substantiven, die mehrere Genera haben, findest du hier: [Liste deutscher Substantive mit mehreren Genera](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/liste-deutscher-substantive-mit-mehreren-genera)

Wörter, die alle drei Geschlechter haben können, sind sehr selten. Aus der oben genannten Liste ist das nur:

- **der/die/das Joghurt**
  Milchprodukt
  das Joghurt: In Österreich
  der Joghurt: überall sonst
  die Joghurt: gibt es laut Duden auch

Der/die/das Unbill war mir neu und steht noch nicht in dieser Liste.

Mit fällt auch sonst kein Wort ein, das mit allen drei Geschlechtern kompatibel ist. Auch von *die/der Butter* kenne ich keine sächliche Variante, nicht mal bei mir daheim in Österreich (um auf einen Kommentar Bezug zu nehmen, der bei der Frage gepostet wurde).

Comment: umindestens kann man auf Österreichisch/Bairisch sagen, dass der Teufel auch alle drei Geschlechter hat (und das auch noch in einem ganzen Satz) : **Das die der Deifi hol**.   (duck)

Comment: Ich, der ich Bayer bin, würde es als „di“ schreiben, um „dich“ auszudrücken. So würde klar werden, dass es sich dabei nicht um einen Artikel handelt. Und das Wort „Das“ würde ich mit zwei „s“ schreiben, wenn wir schon korrekt sein wollen, aber für die bairischen Dialekte gibt es ja keine verbindliche Rechtschreibung. ;-)

Comment: @Nemgathos: Das sehe ich auch so. Und in den österreichischen Varianten der bairischen Dialekte wird das einzige Wort in dem Satz, das wirklich ein Artikel ist, zu *»da«.* und das *»I«* am Ende des Antichristen wird zu einem vokalisiertem *»L«,* dafür wird das *»L«* am Ende des Verbs zu einem *»I«.* Außerdem ist das *»D/T«* hart: **Dass di da Teifl hui!**

Answer (score 2):

Ich hab' da mal was zusammengesucht und den Duden als Referenz genommen, es sind ganz schön viele geworden:

der, die, das, *Band* (OK, *die* Band spricht sich anders)

der, die, das, *Kiefer* (Baum f, oder Körperteil sowohl n,m)

der, die, das, *Weise* (schlauer Mann oder Frau, Melodie, Art, und das Substantiv von weise)

der, die, das, *Halfter* (n und m Pferdegeschirr, n und f Pistolentasche)

der, die, das,  *Triangel* (hier tatsächlich dreimal dasselbe Ding)

Bei Neologismen ist man überhaupt sehr großzügig:

der, die, das, *Bongo* (Trommel n und f, Antilopenart m OKOK, sehr exotisch, der Duden hat's aber)

der, die das *Bookmark* ist in allen drei Genera im Duden gelistet

der, die, das, *Cap* (Baseballkappe) gibt's im Duden auch in allen drei Genera

der, die, das *Python* (Die Schlange m und f, die Programmiersprache n, letztere noch nicht im Duden)

der, die, das *Flipchart* (immer dasselbe Ding)

der, die, das *Ischias* (der Nerv, die Krankheit)

der, die, das *Korpus* (Textbelegsammlung, Körper, Schriftart)

der, die das, *Paprika* (das Gewürz n, das Gemüse m oder f)

der, die das, *Queue* (der Billardstock (n und m) und die Schlange - zugegebenermaßen sehr selten)

der, die, das *Zigarillo* (im Duden in allen drei Genera)